# Bootstrap - dropdown creates scrollbar to parent DIV

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap dropdown creates scrollbars to parent div when it is placed at the bottom. Does anyone know how to fix it?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xMddf/47/) for this.

It is easy to set `overflow: hidden` Or `overflow: visible` on `bs-example` class. But i need scrollbars, because i'll add contents to that div dynamically. At that time it needs scroll bars. Even though i have scrollbars dropdown is pushed down to the bottom. Can't dropdown float over the scrollbars OR Can i open upward when there is not enough space at the bottom?

Answer (score 11):

You must use overflow: inherit; instead of auto.

http://jsfiddle.net/gildonei/xMddf/1131/

```css
.bs-example
{
    margin: 30px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #F00;
    overflow: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="bs-example">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Default <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I asked 3d to solve a ticket regarding this issue in all the pages of application. Your answer solved in it 3s! Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xMddf/48/)**

**css**

```
.bs-example
{
    margin: 30px;
   height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**[demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/xMddf/49/)**

**css**

```
.bs-example
{
    margin: 30px;
   min-height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: i think you didn't read my question fully. I know these solutions. I need dropdown float over that div. not inside it, by using it's space

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem with sleepless night.[image]

open the image in new tab as i was not able to upload JSFiddle on stakoverflow